# Textarea locking

Tags: php, html

I have a simple survey form i designed but for some reason one line of code isnt working.

In question 5. If the user selected the radio button YES then they must enter something in the textarea or the form must not be sent.

If no then the textarea should be locked so nothing can be entered.

Here is the code: Thanks for the help ladies and gentleman

```html
5. Are you using other non-franchise service centres? 
<br>
*if yes is there any other reason you would do so other than price
<br>
<input type="radio" name="question5"
<?php if (isset($question5) && $question5=="Yes") echo "checked";?>
value="Yes">Yes
<br>
<input type="radio" name="question5"
<?php if (isset($question5) && $question5=="No") echo "checked";?>
value="No">No
<br>
<textarea name="question5" rows="5" cols="40"><?php echo $question5 </textarea>
```

Comment: php runs on the server. it can NOT do anything with the form after it's sent to the client. you need javascript.

Comment: @MarcB i mean before it sends it sir. The form should realise that if question 5 has a Yes then they must enter something in the textarea. If no then the textarea is locked.

Comment: Try with JavaScript

Comment: then what's the problem? you already have logic to modify the form based on other values - the exact same type of logic would apply to the textarea. And technically speaking, from a user interface point of view, if you don't allow anythign to be entered in the field, and that's set by the php code at page generation time, a nicer way of doing that is to simply NOT output the textarea in the first place.

Comment: @Abdulla how would i do this sir?

Answer (score 1):

Option1: hide the textarea

```js
function check5(selectedType){
  if (selectedType == 'Yes'){
    document.getElementById('5textarea').style.display = 'block'; 
 
  } else{
    
    document.getElementById('5textarea').style.display = 'none';
  
  }
}
```

```html
5. Are you using other non-franchise service centres? 
<br>
*if yes is there any other reason you would do so other than price
<br>
<input type="radio" name="question5"  value="Yes" onclick="check5(this.value)"> Yes
<br>
<input type="radio" name="question5" value="No" onclick="check5(this.value)"> No
<br>

<textarea id="5textarea" name="question5" rows="5" cols="40" style="display:none"></textarea>
```

Option2:  enable/disable the textarea (**NOT TESTED**):

```
5. Are you using other non-franchise service centres? 
<br>
*if yes is there any other reason you would do so other than price
<br>
<input type="radio" name="question5"  value="Yes" onclick="check5(this.value)"> Yes
<br>
<input type="radio" name="question5" value="No" onclick="check5(this.value)"> No
<br>
<textarea id="5textarea" name="question5" rows="5" cols="40" disabled="true"></textarea>
```

and change the javascript to:

```
function check5(selectedType){
if (selectedType == 'Yes'){
  document.getElementById("5textarea").disabled = false;

} else{

  document.getElementById("5textarea").disabled = true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it with javascript since PHP only runs on the server, **not in the browser**!

In this code, the textarea is disabled if not needed, and if "Yes" is checked and the textarea doesn't contain enough text, an error appears when submitting the form:

```js
// Javascript:
function validate() {
    var radioYes = document.getElementById('radioYes');
    var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');
    
    if (radioYes.checked && textarea.value.length < 10) {
        alert('Enter at least 10 characters!');
        textarea.focus();
        return false;
    }
}

function toggle(value) {
 document.getElementById('textarea').disabled = value;
}
```

```css
/* CSS: */
* {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML/PHP: -->
<form action="#">
    5. Are you using other non-franchise service centres?<br>
    *if yes is there any other reason you would do so other than price?<br>
    
    <input type="radio" name="question5" value="Yes" onchange="toggle(this.selected)" id="radioYes">Yes<br>
    <input type="radio" name="question5" value="No" onchange="toggle(!this.selected)">No<br>
    
    <textarea id="textarea" name="question5" rows="5" cols="40" disabled></textarea><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Send" onclick="return validate()" />
</form>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qc3ewpmz/4/)